# Delete id from json regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a json array with thousands of elements with `_id` that I want to remove:

```
  [
   {
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"61d6633647ea79714d89fc9c"
      },
      "name":"test"
   },
   {
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"61d6633647ea79714d124124214"
      },
      "name":"test2"
   }
]
```

How can I delete this using a regex in notepad or js? I need to delete the comma aswell

e.g. For the example I need to delete `"_id":{"$oid":"61d6633647ea79714d124124214"},` and `"_id":{"$oid":"61d6633647ea79714d89fc9c"},`

Comment: I would look at deleting with JSON parser prior to using a regex.

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop your array and `delete item._id`, then encode back to JSON string if needed

```js
let jsonArray = [
   {
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"61d6633647ea79714d89fc9c"
      },
      "name":"test"
   },
   {
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"61d6633647ea79714d124124214"
      },
      "name":"test2"
   }
];

for (let item of jsonArray) {
    delete item._id;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonArray));
```